# Rendering an image from node.js within Express() (Azure Mobile Services)

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-mobile-services

I try to render an image with Express from Azure Mobile Services.
I get the image from a SQL Database, no big deal.

But when i try to render my image, it doesn't work as expected.

here is my code :

```
exports.getImage = function (request, response) {

console.log('Getting image param : ' + request.params.imageId);

var imageId = request.params.imageId;
var tableImage = request.service.tables.getTable('Images');

tableImage
    .where({ id: imageId })
    .read({
        success: function (results) {
            var img = results[0];

            // var base64Image = img.imageblob.toString('base64');
            // var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64Image, 'base64');

            console.log('Image Name : ' + img.name + ' ' + img.imageformat);
            var decodedImageBinary = new Buffer(img.imageblob, 'binary');
            var contentType = 'image/' + img.imageformat;

            response.set('Content-Type', contentType);
            response.send(decodedImageBinary);


        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No :) Here is the result :
[Get My Picture Link](https://fabrikamjs.azure-mobile.net/api/getimage/A52FD911-185A-4F77-90E1-3179B7C220BD)
With Fiddler, you can see that (at least for me) everything seems to be ok

Comment: Try `response.end(decodedImageBinary, 'binary');`

Comment: Thx @BenFortune for your time :) I ve already test your solution and the result is exactly the same.